# Update vs TransactWriteItems (dynamodb)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need to update a nested object in an attribute on my dynamo table.
I was batching the array to get the parameters. However, the operation using `TransactWriteItems` fails with the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationException: Invalid
> UpdateExpression: An expression attribute name used in the document
> path is not defined; attribute name: #useAutoCost

I'm sending these params:

```
{
"TransactItems": [
    {
        "Update": {
            "TableName": "XXXXtest",
            "Key": {
                "windFarmTurbineKey": "XXXXX1",
                "key": "testxxx"
            },
            "UpdateExpression": "SET observations.#insp.#manualCost = :manualCost, observations.#insp.#useAutoCost = :useAutoCost",
            "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
                "#insp": "2022-08-18-2",
                "#manualImpact": "manualImpact",
                "#useAutoImpact": "useAutoImpact"
            },
            "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                ":manualImpact": 800,
                ":useAutoImpact": false
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

I followed the second option: use `update` and it works.

I would like to know why this is not possible to update nested objects using `transactWrite`. I don't find any on the docs...

any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[TransactWriteItems can do updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html).

Something failing with `undefined` does not sound write, and we have no way to help without seeing your code.

But there is no difference in a an `UpdateItem` and a batch of `UpdateItems` within a `TrasnactWriteItem`.

#### Edit Your issue:

You have not defined `#useAutoCost` in the AttributeValueNames.

Comment: I updated my question with more data. Thanks